# Throwing food on your clothes

Tags: word-usage

If someone is eating and that falls on the person by mistake,  what will be a natural way to describe that?  Actually a kid's eating and when  he throws it on himself,  his mom asks him to be more careful and the boy replies:

> I threw it on myself, not you.
>
> It fell on me,  not you.

What sounds better #1 or #2? What would you use if neither of these sound natural?

Comment: I have a sloppy child.  I would say, "It spilled on me, not on you."

Answer (score 2):

Purely in terms of describing *falls on the person* ***by mistake***, then *I threw it* would not be a good fit.

To say *I threw it* implies intention on the part of the person doing the throwing. If it's unintentional, then, between the two phrases, *it fell on me* is a better description—because it has no direct agent for the action.

---

Another way of expressing it could be *I dropped it on myself by mistake.* The addition of *by mistake* helps express the fact that it was an accident.

Note that *dropped* is a specific verb that *by mistake* works with. It would sound odd to say *I threw it on myself by mistake*. So, regardless of the additional wording, the verb *throw* isn't the right choice in this context.

Comment: So does "it fell on me" sound natural or will it be better to use "it dropped on me."?

Comment: And will it be natural to use "it dropped on me" Or will it only be "I dropped it on me".

Comment: @It'saboutEnglish There's no clear expression that's *better*. I would *personally* say *I dropped it by mistake* (if not something totally different like *it was an accident*), but there's nothing wrong with the other expressions. (Except for the one with *throw*, which I would avoid.)

Comment: And should it be "I dropped it on me" Or "I dropped it on myself".

Comment: @It'saboutEnglish It's *I dropped it on myself* but *it dropped on me*. The first is reflexive, the second is not.